# Why does select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor) include an extra junk character?

Tags: c++, qt

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
Qt 4.8.4

I am using `QTextCursor` to grab each block's text. I use `select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor)` to grab the text and then go to the next block with `movePosition(QTextCursor::NextBlock)`. But when I again `select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor)` I get an extra junk character in the `QString` and the anchor has moved to the end of the previous block.

Using this for text.txt:

```
A
B
```

This code's comments walks through the issue and asks the questions:

```
 #include <QTGui>
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow*          window = new QMainWindow;
    QTextEdit*            editor = new QTextEdit(window);
    QTextDocument*      document = new QTextDocument(window);

    editor->setDocument(document);
    QFile file("test.txt");
    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        editor->setPlainText(file.readAll());

    QTextBlock block = document->begin();
    QTextCursor* cursor = new QTextCursor(document);
    int pos = cursor->position();           // = 0
    int anchor = cursor->anchor();          // = 0

    cursor->select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
    pos = cursor->position();               // = 1
    anchor = cursor->anchor();              // = 0

    QString text = cursor->selectedText();  // = "A"
    int size = text.size();                 // = 1

    cursor->movePosition(QTextCursor::NextBlock);
    pos = cursor->position();               // = 2
    anchor = cursor->anchor();              // = 2

    cursor->select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
    pos = cursor->position();               // = 3
    anchor = cursor->anchor();              // = 1 Why not 2?

    text = cursor->selectedText();          // "B" in debugger
                                            // but text.at(0) = junk & test.at(1) = "B"
    size = text.size();                     // = 2 Why? Why not 1?

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not junk. The first character includes the U+2029 paragraph separator (HTML:   PSEP). In other words, selecting the block includes the starting paragraph separator. The first block doesn't have a starting SEP. Therefore, need to exclude the first character if one wants to extract the text alone of subsequent blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation values has to do with the nature of a `QTextBlock`, and how navigating by block and what is determined by `BlockUnderCursor`.  The documentation gives some insight into this:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/qtextblock.html#details

Here is another part of the documentation seemed helpful to me:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/qtextblockformat.html#details

I haven't experimented with what you found, but here are some of my thoughts on it:

In some ways I think of it like pressing Ctrl+Up or Ctrl+Down in Windows in a MS Word document.  Some of it may have to do with the line endings you are using.  "\r\n" v. "\n".  I know that sometimes the "eof" character is weird to work with.  Some documents and formats require a new line before the end of file character.

Hope that helps.